# Why asp.net mvc running on a double localhost in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I'm curious upon running on my web application in IIS Express I saw a double localhost in Browse Applications. Please refer to the screenshot provided. I just want to know why it suddenly appears two  localhost, is not normal or anyone can explain why? This is a newly created project.

[image]

Comment: by the way this is newly created project.

Comment: I guess because one is HTTP and one is HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you enabled SSL, by entering to your “Project Properties” and setting “SSL Enabled = True”. IIS Express will then host your application on both protocols.

[image]